# Various variants of modular forms

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms

There are many different generalizations of modular forms. One has Hilbert modular forms, Siegel modular forms, Maass wave forms, Jacobi forms, and then there are various generalities of automorphic forms. There are level structures and weights, there are adelic forms and cusp forms, and all sorts of algebraic groups and subgroups.

I'm having much trouble grasping all these different notions. Could someone perhaps give an overview of the various versions of modular and automorphic forms, along with their respective relevance? Specifically, I am interested in the Langlands conjecture, and its connection with homotopy theory (in which I have a reasonable background).

Comment: This question is extremely broad. I'd encourage you to look at one of the many survey papers on the Langlands programme to help you make your question more specific.

Comment: @reuns I'm not sure that is the question, given that the OP talks about Maass forms and Jacobi forms. If the question is indeed about the connection between Galois representations and automorphic representations, I can recommend some great survey papers, but I'd need 5+ pages to even scratch the surface.

Comment: These two are pretty good: [one](https://01416e54-a-62cb3a1a-s-sites.googlegroups.com/site/wushijig/intro_vancouver.pdf?attachauth=ANoY7coUn6K31u63bMJzu6qY-BccGES9zv3lZnw0VNCl4nVGSw30sNqvaumS4sOuxqwfq39bWbWQyGKZ_4iJA5PMvmUqknN1xPg2IoSrK_k4Ih7XDRKfgC3D8r4F-AbmxeFcveA5tgcyWMrGWH4u3YXb_Y52aDrK7ABCJtIuoqi-XvdksSh1OFFn9nu39bZUKmNv8fMuxOa2U3p506X54_g8Hs_ca6uuQw%3D%3D&attredirects=0), [two](https://www.math.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~tetsushi/files/hakuba200611.pdf), although both assume at least some familiarity with the ideas of the Langlands program.

Comment: For a purely Galois theoretic introduction to the Langlands programme, I'd recommend watching the lectures from Kevin Buzzard's recent [MSRI course](https://www.msri.org/summer_schools/792/schedules) or reading the lecture notes [here](http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~buzzard/MSRI/)

Comment: Some comments got deleted adding context to the above suggestions: they are more Galois representation theoretic introductions to the Langlands programme. For a general introduction, [Gelbart's](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183551573) is excellent.